# How to end an while loop with a keypress

Tags: c#, console

could someone tell me how i stop this do-while loop with a keypress?

I want to do a "moving" cursor in my console window.

```
do
{
    if (KeyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        downup = downup++;
    }
    else if (KeyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
    {
        downup = downup-1;
    }
    else if (KeyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
    {
        leftright = leftright -1;
    }
    else if (KeyInput.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
    {
        leftright = leftright++;
    } 

} while (KeyInput.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: Add a break statements.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
do 
{
    var key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
    if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
    {
        downup++;
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
    {
        downup -= 1;
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
    {
        leftright -= 1;
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
    {
        leftright++;
    } 
} while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Thinking about your original code, I suspect the problem is that you already have code outside of the loop (not posted) to read the key from the console; the important change here is that this needs to happen inside the loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

so you mean like this?

```
         do {
            int downup, leftright;
            downup = 10;
            leftright = 10;

            Console.SetCursorPosition(downup, leftright);
            Console.Write("█");

            var key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                downup++;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                downup -= 1;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                leftright -= 1;
            }
            else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                leftright++;
            }
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var looping = true;
while(looping)
{
    switch(Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
    {
      case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
        downup++;
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        downup--;
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
        leftright--;
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
        leftright++;
        break;
      case ConsoleKey.Escape;
        looping = false;
        break;
    }
}
```